Is this a good model for how people coexist with each other?
A model for how people coexist with each other.
I recently read these two books by David Graeber and I've been dipping lightly into related topics of philosophy and sociology.

Debt: The First 5,000 Years
The Dawn of Everything

I'm trying to create a model that allows me to describe the systems that people create which enable large populations to live together and cooperate.
My current interest is on the descriptive side rather that prescriptive, I'm not trying to solve any problems, just create a model that let's me understand things. I'm looking for things to read that will help me refine my descriptive model.
At a high level, my model defines a set of ideas that are related:

state: defines and enforces laws
law: defines and enforces money and property
property: usage and ownership of items and information
money: mechanism for the exchange of property

The modern world is a complex system with lots of moving parts.  But so far I don't have to work too hard to fit all of it into the model of the four things listed above.
Details:
In order to say that we have laws at all, it implies an enforcement mechanism.  Laws without enforcement aren't really laws.
When I visualize those dependencies I see something like: a (State/Law) system that defines and supports a (Property/Money) system.
So far none of this attempts to define how people act (or should act) under such a system or how to make intentional changes to such a system.  I guess you could describe my model so far as taxonomic.
Rights:
I don't think I need to include a thing called "rights" in my model.  That word seems to be used in different ways.

"I have a right to my possessions." This seems like an aspect of law and property.
"Minorities should have equal rights." This seems more aspirational (prescriptive) than descriptive.

It seems like anything specific that we call a "right" could be defined as a restriction on what other people can do.  That would place it in the realm of law and property.
Autonomy:
In my model, rights or laws involving personal freedom would need to treat the physical person as a kind of property that's primarily owned by the person themself.  This also makes the concept of slavery fit into the descriptive model.  It seems a little weird at first to treat myself as my own property. (It might seems less weird if I was a former slave myself.)
Where next?:
How does my model stack up against other attempts to define these things at a high level?  Any recommendations on what to read next?

Note that there are different kinds of property rights in a single system, see usus, fructus and abusus in roman law and other legal systems influenced by it (almost every single current legal system). Your point about being yourself being your own property reminded me of it. You might own yourself, but in most of the world it's illegal to sell yourself to someone like you would do with your other properties like a car or a house, so it's not the same kind of property.
